# Storing LINQ queries as variables/constants?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Say I have a LINQ-to-XML query that generates an anonymous type like this:

```
var aQuery =
               (from a in document.Root.Elements("items")
                select new {
                    id = a.Attribute("id").Value,
                    type = a.Attribute("type").Value,
                    modified = a.Attribute("modified").Value
                });
```

if there a way to store that query expression in a variable or constant and then execute at runtime? The basic idea is that I have a bunch of these expressions and it would be handy if they could all be defined in one place and then invoked dynamically thru a single method where I just need to pass in the XML document and which expression to use. Thanks.

Comment: "if there a way to store that query expression in a variable or constant and then execute at runtime?" You did it yourself already, by storing the query in aQuery variable...

Comment: I think you're missing the point. Obviously it can be stored as a local variable otherwise nothing in Linq would work the way it does. But you cannot define a class-level variable of type 'var' which is what I was driving at

Comment: I can see where the question could be misinterpreted, but I was looking for exactly what OP was and thus understood it just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define them as methods quite easily, though you'd forfit the right to use anonymous types.

```
public static IQueryable<Item> GetItemsFromXml(XDocument document)
{
    return (from a in document.Root.Elements("items") 
            select new Item 
            {
                Id = a.Attribute("id").Value, 
                Type = a.Attribute("type").Value, 
                Modified = a.Attribute("modified").Value 
            }); 
}
```

Having said that, patterns like the repository pattern are used to wrap the whole process of accessing data.

Comment: yeah unfortunately it needs to be anonymous...its no big deal, I was mainly seeking to do it for organizational purposes, thanks